# Why would my webservice method get called via GET?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a asp.net 3.5 site with a *.asmx that serves several webservice methods. The only client that should be calling these methods is one I wrote, and it calls them using a POST request. However, my error logs show many InvalidOperationException errors due to these methods being called with a GET request.

Question: What might be causing these GET requests? Might proxies convert POST requests to GET requests without the client making the request knowing about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to expand on rusanu's answer, bots and crawlers and/or hackers?

Comment: Hackers were my first assumption, but it happens way too often. If it's hackers, they aren't discrete. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

bots and crawlers?

Comment: I'm not sure how a bot would find the URL to be called. The user agent strings are almost always empty. Those that aren't I can pin to users trying to call the service from their browser.

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible there is a bug in your client app. Why not get hold of an HTTP sniffer so you can see exactly what requests are being sent.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. The client is a MSVC C++ application using ATL classes to access the web services. Perhaps they default to using GET under certain situations?

Comment: I stepped through the client code and verified the ATL SOAP classes always set the method to POST. I still think something along the network path is changing the request from POST to GET. Thanks.